# Little program crashes after taking a input

Tags: c

I'm absolutely new to C language and computer science. I'm still learning how to code. This down below is a little program I wrote which converts the height in cm to feet and inches, however, the terminal crashes after it takes the `height_cm` as an input. I thought for a long time but cannot figure out the reason behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float height_cm;
    float feet=(int)(height_cm/2.54)/12;
    float inch=(height_cm/2.54);

    while(height_cm > 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a height in centimeters(<=0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%.2f", &height_cm);
        printf("%.2f = %d feet, %.2f inches", height_cm,feet,inch);
    }
    printf("Bye");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You haven't assigned any value to height_cm before you calculate feet, inch, or enter the while loop.

Comment: When you calculate the values of `feet` and `inch`, what is the value of `height_cm`? C programs never redo calculations retroactively.

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger like gdb? This could help you determine which line causes a segfault (assuming thats the error you are getting)

Comment: Debug your code! Debugging will help you understand issues and help you solve them much easier than staring at your code and wonder what's wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying `%d` for your `feet` variable which is quite clearly a `float`, though oddly it's a `float` based on a rounded value, so you could use `int` if you wanted.

Turn on warnings like `-Wall` to be alerted to simple mistakes like this.

You'll also want to check for *uninitialized variables* as these are the primary source of crashes.

You can't use `while` on a variable that isn't defined. You must define it first.

Consider restructuring:

```
float height_cm;

while (true)
{
    printf("Enter a height in centimeters(<=0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%.2f", &height_cm);

    if (height_cm > 0) {
      int feet = (height_cm/2.54)/12;
      float inch = (height_cm/2.54) % 12; // Don't forget to modulo

      printf("%.2f = %d feet, %.2f inches", height_cm,feet,inch);
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
}
```

Due to how you're asking for input and looping around it you'll want to conditionally `break` rather than express the break condition in the `while` itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for these useful advice, this really helps me a lot!

Comment: Defining variables inside a loop is bad practice in most cases. In your answer, it will create a new `feet` and `inch` space in memory every single time the user enters something greater than 0.

Comment: @ejderuby That's zero cost. An optimizing compiler will put those in registers since they're only used briefly, or worst case use a spot on the stack. They're not dynamically allocated and do not need to be released. That's mostly academic consideration since this loop only runs as fast as a human can input values so it's not performance-critical code anyway.

Answer (score 6):

**Your main problem:** You are referencing a unassigned variable `height_cm` when you are calculating `feet` and `inches`. This is going to produced a **undefined behavior** because the value in that variable is a junk value. The below snipped of code addresses some of you other problems, such as using `%.2f` in `scanf`, and performs your desired logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float height_cm; // Currently junk value
    int feet;        // Currently junk value
    float inch;      // Currently junk value

    // Keep calculating feet / inches as long as the entered hight is positive
    do {
        printf("Enter a height in centimeters(<=0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%f", &height_cm); // Can only use "%.2f for printf not scanf"
        feet=(int)(height_cm/2.54)/12;
        inch=(height_cm/2.54);

        // Output results
        printf("%.2f = %d feet, %.2f inches", height_cm,feet,inch);
    }
    while (height_cm > 0);

    printf("Bye");

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you are checking `height_cm` before assigning it a value. You can make a simple change to execute the loop at least once prior to checking for `0` by replacing the `while` with a `do ... while` loop:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
    float height_cm;
    float feet=(int)(height_cm/2.54)/12;
    float inch=(height_cm/2.54);

    do 
        {
        printf("Enter a height in centimeters(<=0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%.2f", &height_cm);
        printf("%.2f = %d feet, %.2f inches", height_cm,feet,inch);
        } while(height_cm > 0);
    printf("Bye");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: No it still calculates the stuff outside the loop